# Telnet works from one network but doesn't work's from another when trying to connect EC2 instance on port 3306

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group

I'm running MySQL server on an EC2 instance on AWS. I've configured security groups to listen at port 3306 and port 22(ssh only from my ip!). But to my surprise, I wasn't able to remotely connect to my ec2 instance on port 3306 from one of my networks as it always gives connection refused, but when I switched my network I'm able to connect.

I'm unable to understand this behaviour as both my networks are working absolutely fine and also I'm not sure if I face similar kind of issue in future, how will I be sure that port 3306 is working?

Answer (score 0):

Only MySQL uses port 3306. You can use netstat command to check if port 3306 is being used or not. Also you can check the firewall rule of the network ( from which you are not able to connect) if something is  preventing to connect port 3306. I am assuming that all security inbound and outbound rules are already present.